# placeholder text as model tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I use a ruby model as placeholder text in a text field input?

I tried this:

```
  <%= text_field_tag 'name', nil, placeholder: size[:name], 'Name'%>

  <%= text_field_tag 'name', nil, placeholder: <%= size[:name] %> 'Name'%>
```

but neither work.

What is the syntax for this?

Comment: where is `size` coming from and what does it contain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use string interpolation (requires a double quoted string):

```
 <%= text_field_tag 'name', nil, placeholder: "#{size[:name]} Name" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is partly correct in the usage of `<%=...%>` tags but the second one is not correct.  You cannot nest erb expression tags like you've done in this line:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'name', nil, placeholder: <%= size[:name] %> 'Name'%>
```

The solution is to use string concatenation or string interpolation as @PinnyM has answered.

With String concatenation:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'name', nil, placeholder: size[:name].to_s + 'Name' %>
```

With interpolation as @PinnyM has already shown:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'name', nil, placeholder: "#{size[:name]} Name" %>
```